# nginx alis works but it is not returning correct mime type

Tags: nginx

I have setup one nginx rule

```
    location ~ /(sitemap.*) {
      alias /var/www/html/sitemaps/$1;
    }
```

This works good for cases that I want like example

1. https://example.com/sitemap-1.xml
2. returns file /var/www/html/sitemaps/sitemap-1.xml

My issue is that that in response headers content type is `content-type: text/plain`  and not correct for xml file

Any way for nginx to automatically understand the content type and return proper header ?

Comment: Most Nginx configurations use `include mime.types;` to match file extensions to a MIME type. This needs to be within scope (i.e. in a parent block of this `location` block). Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and check that the MIME types are being loaded and are in scope.

Comment: Thanks I checked and there is no match for search `mime` in my nginx.conf. Can I use `include mime.types;` inside my location block `location ~ /(sitemap.*) { or` MUST be in parent level. I want to use directives only when needed to avoid other things potentially misbehaving/breaking

Comment: So my question is can it be any performance problem or issue with other locations if I enable mime.types in server level ? I want mime types to be used only for location sitemaps that I posted here, all other locations (which are a lot) are working fine and don't want any impact in performance or other kind there

Comment: I added `include mime.types;` just after `http {` as you suggested and after nginx restart is working fine. Still am curious to learn above questions if it can affect anything else. Thanks

Comment: The `mime.types` file simply contains a [`types` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) and can be inserted in the `http`, `server` or `location` block. It's usual to place common directives as high as possible to avoid duplication, but it's certainly not required, and including it in a single `location` is perfectly valid.